Run script using onEdit(e) if checkbox 'checked' on a particular sheet
To get round not being able to 'click' buttons in GoogleSheets when using a cellphone I've created an onEdit Trigger to operate a function that runs when a checkbox in cell D5 on a particular sheet is checked.
The script works well but if I uncheck the checkbox the script runs again.
Is there anyway to prevent this?
Thanks
function onEdit(e) { 
  myfunction1(e)
 }
function myfunction1(e) {
  if (!e.value) return
  if (e.value !== "TRUE") return
  if (e.range.rowStart !== 5) return
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 4) return
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() !==  "Create New Orders") return
  orderFromSheet()
  e.range.uncheck()
  }

I've searched for answers but not been able to find a solution.

If you are only checking the value of D5, here is what I would do:
function onEdit(e) {
  // A1 Notation lets you just check for the string value of cell 'D5'
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "D5" && e.range.getValue() == true){

    orderFromSheet()

    // You don't really need to set the value programatically here,
    // unless there is something I don't understand about the way
    // you are interacting with your phone and Google Sheets...
    e.range.setValue(true)
  }
}


If you use an installable trigger you can perform some functions that require permission
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");//debug
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Create New Orders" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart == 5 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate");//debug
    orderFromSheet();
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");//set back to true to use checkbox as a button
  }
}

